# Where to find hard logic problems

Tags: combinatorics, reference-request, problem-solving, puzzle

I was searching for hard logic problems like for example counterfeit coin problem or the problems about merging two sorted sequences of weighted balls. Whenever I was searching for serious logical problems I couldn't find anything university level (only like 5th or 6th frade level at most).
I'm wondering if there is a book containing serious logical problems (and maybe even answers).

Comment: You can look up “Einstein’s logic puzzle”, which is pretty tough. You can also go through LSAT logic games prep. Or, you can try to prove Hypothetical Syllogism in the Hilbert-style system provided on Wikipedia without using the Deduction Theorem.

Comment: I have suppressed the tag "logic" (you are not dealing with expressions such that $\forall x \exists y f(x,y) \lor g(x,y)$ for example), but have added the tag "puzzle".

Comment: @PW_246 Thanks very much I was wondering if there is one source maybe a book or a course that would contain a lot of various  "logic puzzles"(that aren't alike at all and make you think a lot before finding the answers or make assumptions).I know the Einstein puzzle and have worked through some of lsat puzzles, they were somewhat easy. I will definitely check the latter, thanks!

Comment: @JeanMarie thanks for the correction.

Comment: There are many books on "advanced logical puzzles". I advise in particular all the books with Martin Gardner as author or co-author.

Comment: You can also search on this site with this request : [puzzle] : there are scores of questions tagged like this, for example [this recent one](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4704045/305862).